# Node.js how to read and write arrays to file as binary

Tags: arrays, node.js, binary, buffer

I have a big array that I need to read in from a file. Normally I would save it as JSON, but the size of the UTF-8 encoded file is substantially larger and I have very strict size requirements so every Kb is precious.

Here's what I have so far:

```
// https://www.npmjs.com/package/typedarray-to-buffer
var toBuffer = require('typedarray-to-buffer');
var buffer =  toBuffer(myArray);
var wstream = fs.createWriteStream('./myArray');
wstream.write(buffer);

// later...
var buff = new Buffer(data); // <-- file data passed in as a buffer
myArray =  buff; // <--still binary :-(
```

I'm following this [helpful article about writing binary files](http://codewinds.com/blog/2013-08-19-nodejs-writable-streams.html#writing_binary_file) but it doesn't cover how to read them back in. I think the part I'm stuck in is turning the buffer data back into an array.

*Update*

Here's the `console.log()` for the array before it's written to file:

```
Int32Array {
  '0': 2107281600,
  '1': -370226405,
  '2': 274543611,
  '3': 172775319,
  '4': -1927927544,
  '5': -248215383,
  '6': -1295527238,
  '7': -1774538531,
  '8': -784581845,
  '9': 651425656,
  '10': -534521241,
  '11': -1788883022,
  '12': 1679049410,
  '13': -1728518340,
  ...
```

Comment: buff.toString('utf-8') ? not sure what s your problem.

Comment: @mh-cbon that might have been my problem! ;-) want to submit an answer?

Comment: note that under node it seems useless, see: `If this module is used in node, then it will just call new Buffer. This is just for the convenience of modules that work in both node and the browser.`

Comment: @mh-cbon I tried adding `buff.toString('utf-8')` but it didnt' work. When I logged the resulting "array" I see `�+^k�[:�����'w�!�k?2�Ͽ�庀�%�*|�1i������,�ó�b�;�����b����n���T{l���b�tI�/xڶ��G�Ϳ���`��k�D�Z`...

Comment: can you show what is myArray made of ? Can you show where is data coming from ?

Comment: @mh-cbon Do you mean before writing it to the file?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112521/discussion-between-mh-cbon-and-emersonthis).

Answer (score -1):

It is actually very simple to write binary to file. Use the "binary" encoding type string for the writeFileSync method from FS. Like so :

```
// Assume you have an Int32Array called myArray

var fs = require('fs');
fs.writeFileSync('/tmp/test.bin', myArray, 'binary');
```

Now you can check that the size of the file matches the byte size of the typed array. For example, myArray.length*4 will be the size of your data which in my case is 1228624. The file system says :

```
$ ls -l /tmp/test.bin
-rw-rw-r-- 1 flatmax flatmax 1228624 May  5 17:58 /tmp/test.bin
```

Comment: 'binary' is the same as 'latin1'. Yes, I know that makes no sense.